# How to fetch data from External API in custom created admin grid in magento2

Tags: magento2

Is there any method that can fetch data from external API ?
Basically i have created a grid in admin page & in that grid i want to display the data from External API.

Answer (score 0):

Should use uiComponent and provide a DataProvider which implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProviderInterface or extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider.

There are example on the documentation: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/concepts/data-source/